# Thread is running one after another but not at the same time how can I fix that?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following code, which is used to watch a directory and on a creation of a file a thread starts, it should read a CSV file and save the values of it in an object, after that I use the data saved in the object to sort the data from the CSV file in new directory depending on some strategies defined in a config.proprties file, when I paste some files in the directory that is being watched, it gets processed one after another, but what I want is to make them run at the same time unless I have more than one file that will use the same strategy can someone advice what am I doing wrong?

Here is my Watcher class:

```
    public class MyWatchService extends Thread {

        private final Path path;
        private PropertiesValue propertiesValue;

        public MyWatchService(Path file) {
            propertiesValue = new PropertiesValue(file.toString());
            this.path = file;
        }

        public void doOnChange(String path) {
            String fullPath = MyWatchService.this.path + "/" + path;

            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    propertiesValue.validatePatternAndCheckCase(path, fullPath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Do on changes in the dir: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                path.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE);
                while (true)
                    checkForEvents(watchService);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread: " + e);
            }
        }

        private void checkForEvents(java.nio.file.WatchService watchService) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for events");
                WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
                List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey.pollEvents();
                events.forEach((e) -> getUpdates(e));
                watchKey.reset();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Checking For Events: " + e);
            }
        }

        private void getUpdates(WatchEvent<?> e) {
            Path updatedPath = (Path) e.context();
            doOnChange(updatedPath.toString());
        }
    }
```

And here is the class that used to read the property file and match it with file that have been created:

```
public class PropertiesValue {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    private Config config = new Config();
    private String path;
    ReadCSVFile a = new ReadCSVFile();

    public PropertiesValue(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    private void checkInputStream(Properties properties, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null)
            properties.load(inputStream);
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + fileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    public void caseCheck(List<Transactions> listOfTrans) throws Exception {
        StratgyImpl strategy = new StratgyImpl();
        config = validatePattern(path);
        String keys = config.getStrategy();
        String path = config.getPath();
        checkStrategy(listOfTrans, strategy, keys, path);
    }


    private void checkStrategy(List<Transactions> listOfTrans, StratgyImpl strategy, String keys, String path) throws Exception {
        for (Transactions transaction : listOfTrans) {
            if (keys.equals("1")) {
                path = "/home/user/ATM/" + transaction.getIban() + "/";
                strategy.imp(1).getDestPathForTransaction(path, transaction,
                        config);// .getDestPathForTransaction(path, t, config);
            } else if (keys.equals("2")) {
                path = "/home/user/OP/" + transaction.getCurrency() + "/";
                strategy.imp(2).getDestPathForTransaction(path, transaction,
                        config);//byCurrency.getDestPathForTransaction(path, t, config);
            } else if (keys.equals("3")) {
                path = "/home/user/PA/" + transaction.getTransactionTime() + "/";
                strategy.imp(3).getDestPathForTransaction(path, transaction, config);
            } else if (keys.equals("4")) {
                path = "/home/user/Transactions/" + transaction.getTransactionType() + "/";
                strategy.imp(4).getDestPathForTransaction(path, transaction,
                        config);//byType.getDestPathForTransaction(path, t, config);
            }
        }
    }

    public Config validatePattern(String path) throws IOException {
        try {
            return getConfig(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Validating Pattern Failed: " + e);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        System.out.println("This file does not match any pattern: " + path);
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized void validatePatternAndCheckCase(String path, String fullPath) throws Exception {
        validatePattern(path);
        caseCheck(a.readFile(fullPath));
    }

    private Config getConfig(String path) throws IOException {
        Properties properties;
        String fileName;
        Set<String> value;
        properties = new Properties();
        fileName = "config.properties";
        inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        checkInputStream(properties, fileName);
        value = properties.stringPropertyNames();
        getStrategyAndPath(path, properties, value);
        return config;
    }

    private void getStrategyAndPath(String path, Properties properties, Set<String> value) {
        String key;
        String[] strings;
        for (String val : value) {
            key = (String) properties.get(val);
            strings = key.split(",");
            if (path.matches(val)) {
                config.setStrategy(strings[0]);
                config.setPath(strings[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my strategy implementation class:

```
public class StratgyImpl {

    WriteCSV w = new WriteCSV();

    public Strategies imp(int id) throws Exception {
        if (id == 1) {
            return (path, transaction, config) -> {
                Path newPath;
                if (config != null) {
                    newPath = Paths.get(path.toString());
                    w.writeFile(transaction, path);
                    return newPath;
                }
                throw new IllegalPathStateException("Path not found: " + path);
            };
        } else if (id == 2) {
            return (path, transaction, config) -> {
                Path newPath;
                if (config != null) {
                    newPath = Paths.get(path.toString());
                    w.writeFile(transaction, path);
                    return newPath;
                }
                throw new IllegalPathStateException("Path not found: " + path);
            };
        } else if (id == 3) {
            return (path, transaction, config) -> {
                Path newPath;
                if (config != null) {
                    newPath = Paths.get(path.toString());
                    w.writeFile(transaction, path);
                    return newPath;
                }
                throw new IllegalPathStateException("Path not found: " + path);
            };
        } else if (id == 4) {
            return (path, transaction, config) -> {
                Path newPath;
                if (config != null) {
                    newPath = Paths.get(path.toString());
                    w.writeFileByTransactionType(transaction, path);
                    return newPath;
                }
                throw new IllegalPathStateException("Path not found: " + path);
            };

        }
        throw new Exception("Could not find the requested strategy");
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following result:

```
Thread Name = Thread-2
Thread Name = Thread-2
Thread Name = Thread-2
Thread Name = Thread-2
Thread Name = Thread-2
Thread Name = Thread-5
Thread Name = Thread-5
Thread Name = Thread-5
Thread Name = Thread-5
Thread Name = Thread-5
Thread Name = Thread-4
Thread Name = Thread-4
Thread Name = Thread-4
Thread Name = Thread-4
Thread Name = Thread-4
Thread Name = Thread-3
Thread Name = Thread-3
Thread Name = Thread-3
Thread Name = Thread-3
Thread Name = Thread-3
```

While all the files have a different strategies to implement!
If someone is interested to help please let me know if you want to see more code :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `validatePatternAndCheckCase()` is synchronized, only one thread may execute this method at a time.  All other threads trying to execute this method while another thread is executing it will be forced to wait.  Since this is the method that all of your threads are calling, only one of your threads will be able to proceed at a time, negating the purpose of using threads for concurrent execution.

Comment: I see that, but if removed the synchronized from there and got two files that will use the same strategy it will run concurrently and I want to avoid that just in this case

Comment: is there any way to achieve what am I after?

Comment: You will need to have a distinct object instance you can synchronize on for each different strategy.